# What is the best layout to use for this ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Is RelativeLayout the best way to lay something like out?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinearLayout with using weights. This is the exact thing you want. Just change text colours, sizes, layout sizes,etc (I used values just to show how it looks, you will customise).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="#484848"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

`LinearLayout`s are my personal preference.

One horizontal `LinearLayout`, containing an `ImageView`, a vertical `LinearLayout` with two `TextView`s and another `TextView`

Give the `ImageView` a fixed height and width (48dp is really common for list items).

Set the width of the vertical `LinearLayout` to 0dp and give it a weight of 1. This way it will stretch all the way so the `ImageView` and the `TextView` will be on the edge of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

I would stay with the `RelativeLayout` due to reduced depth in your View hierarchy compared to using multiple `LinearLayout`s to represent the same layout.

In theory, this will make your list smoother.

Comment: In practice, too. +1 for spotting this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEXT1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEXT2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="TEXT3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```